# Geometry tool kit recommendations

Tags: geometry

I'm replacing my old geometry tools that I've owned for many years, and I've had a good look around, but for the most part I can't find much information at all about which sets and companies make the best quality tool sets.

For the most part, most sets seem to be of poor quality, and marketed predominately towards school kids. Are there good, recognised companies and geometry sets that you can recommend that are:

1. Sturdy and won't need to be replaced in a couple of years.
2. Reliable (I'm thinking mainly about compases - I don't really want slippage when drawing an intricate diagram)
3. Probably least important of the three, but I'd also like them to look nice as well. I like wood, but I know there can be problems with warping tools and environmental
   moisture. The ink sets look fun, but I'm also not a massive fan of
   the ink spillage - I want pretty diagrams more than I want a pretty
   tool kit.

Thanks. Any recommendations would be fabulous.